# Logging after return statement in method && asynchronous logging

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, async-await, background-process

In the web service method, we first go to Oracle. Then we log in the finally block. Since we write to elasticsearch for logging, the service method's return time is too long. We want to do the logging in the background after returning it to the user in the method. We cannot manage threads due to heavy concurrent requests. The service flow is as follows:

[first flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HafjL.png)

We want the flow to be as follows in order to respond faster.

[second flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS1GQ.png)

How can we perform the log writing process independently without returning the data in the background? Which structure can we use? Thanks very much for your recommendations.

Developing more responsive service methods

Comment: To achieve the async logging without blocking main thread that handle the requests you could try these ways:

1) You could create separate microservice for the logging. you can send log information via RESTful calls or a messaging system The microservice processes these log messages independently of your main application.
2) You can use messaging queue which can help push log messages onto the queue and separate logging service will consume these messages and write them into the  Elasticsearch.